# Kubernetes RBAC not working on my Azure AKS Cluster secrets is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac

I'm going around in circles trying to validate my ServiceAccount configuration in an AKS cluster. My aim is to apply only the verbs, resources and API groups that I need, but I've now gone back to the original example, and it's not working.

I have a namespace called "vnd-dev" into which I'm adding a service account as follows:

```bash
kubectl create serviceaccount -n vnd-dev testaccess-user
```

I'm then allowing view access using a similar instruction to the demo kubernetes instruction:

```bash
kubectl create rolebinding testaccess-rolebinding --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=vnd-dev:testaccess-user --namespace=vnd-dev
```

I'm using Postman to test (although I was originally using a token injected into a pod). To get the token to use with Postman, I do 'kubectl create token -n vnd-dev testaccess-user'. I'm using the HTTPS address from my local kubectl's context.

I get a proper result when I try my own namespace:

```
GET {{KUBEAPI}}/api/v1/namespaces/vnd-dev
```

But when I try listing it's secrets I get an error:

```
GET {{KUBEAPI}}/api/v1/namespaces/vnd-dev/secrets

{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "secrets is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:vnd-dev:testaccess-user\" cannot list resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"vnd-dev\"",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "kind": "secrets"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

I can't seem to get around this - and it seems that it should be working. Indeed if I try:

```bash
kubectl auth can-i list namespaces/vnd-dev/secrets -n vnd-dev --as system:serviceaccount:vnd-dev:testaccess-user
```

I get:

```
Warning: resource 'namespaces' is not namespace scoped
yes
```

The two objects that were installed into kubernetes were as follows:

```
kubectl get serviceaccount -n vnd-dev testaccess-user -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-03T11:48:38Z"
  name: testaccess-user
  namespace: vnd-dev
  resourceVersion: "23639989"
  uid: e1bc8d5a-c67d-4031-a9ee-091c116fd959
```

```
kubectl get rolebinding -n vnd-dev testaccess-rolebinding -o yaml

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-03T12:32:21Z"
  name: testaccess-rolebinding
  namespace: vnd-dev
  resourceVersion: "23651007"
  uid: 9e7d0813-2418-4f15-bfe6-068e8ca22a57
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: testaccess-user
  namespace: vnd-dev
```

I'm pretty sure that the ClusterRole "view" should definitely allow me to query /api/v1/namespaces and /api/v1/namespaces/vnd-dev/secrets and so-on, the content of "view" seems to contian all the resources for all read only verbs.

I can only imagine that AKS needs some additional setup or that the "view" cluster role needs to be enabled in some way.

Does anybody have any ideas why this doesn't work for me?

I got pods listing working and then I just noticed that the ClusterRole
"view" doesn't seem to include 'secrets'. Perhaps I need to bind to another role to add in the secrets.

Comment: This question explains to me that I need to use a ClusterRoleBinding to get to /api/v1/namespaces - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877743/kubernetes-rbac-allowed-by-rolebinding-but-cannot-list-resource?rq=2

Comment: The `view` ClusterRole explicitly does not permit access to secrets. You need at least the `edit` role for that, or you need to create your own custom role to permit read-only access to secrets.

Answer (score 0):

I had made too many assumptions about the content of the 'view' clusterrole, and also did not know how to apply it (i.e. via a clusterrolebinding). I have now been able to work out a file that applies the scenario that I need, which is to access secrets within a single namespace. This looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: testaccess-user
  namespace: vnd-dev
---
#Allow access to cluster layer structures that are required
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: testaccess-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
      - ""
  resources:
    - namespaces
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
#Allow access to items in our own namespace
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: testaccess-role
  namespace: vnd-dev
rules:
- apiGroups:
      - ""
  resources:
    - secrets
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
#Cluster Roles such as 'list namespaces' must be clusterrolebindings or there is not enough permission to complete the operation
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: testaccess-clusterrolebinding
  namespace: vnd-dev
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:vnd-dev:testaccess-user
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: testaccess-clusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
#Role permissions within a single target namespace can be added via a non-cluster role-binding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: testaccess-rolebinding
  namespace: vnd-dev
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:vnd-dev:testaccess-user
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: testaccess-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Effectively, the gotcha with Kubernetes is that if you have access to a single namespace, the path /api/v1/namespaces doesn't work at all, so you don't even get to go as deep as your own namespace, or objects within that namespace, the above script effectively allows use of the /namespaces/ span and then those objects beneath begin to function.